# Nest cannot resolve dependencies of ElasticsearchService

Tags: elasticsearch, dependency-injection, nestjs

I'm trying to use ElasticsearchService Nest service and dependencies cannot be resolved

This is package.json relevant modules versions:

```
"@nestjs/common": "^5.5.0",
"@nestjs/core": "^5.5.0",
"@nestjs/elasticsearch": "^6.0.1",
"@types/elasticsearch": "^5.0.34",
"elasticsearch": "^16.3.0",
```

This is an example code:

```
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';
import * as mocha from 'mocha';
import {
  ElasticsearchService,
  ElasticsearchModule,
} from '@nestjs/elasticsearch';
import { Client } from 'elasticsearch';

const clientFactory = {
  provide: Client,
  useFactory: () => {
    return new Client({});
  },
};

mocha.describe('Test Suite', () => {
  let module: TestingModule;
  let elasticsearch: ElasticsearchService;

  before(async () => {
    module = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [ElasticsearchModule],
      providers: [ElasticsearchService, clientFactory],
    }).compile();

    elasticsearch = module.get<ElasticsearchService>(ElasticsearchService);
  });
  it('should be defined', () => {
    console.log('This message does not appears');
  });
});
```

Comment: This is the error: Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the ElasticsearchService (?). Please make sure that the argument at index [0] is available in the ElasticsearchModule context.

Answer (score 0):

Unless this is an e2e test you shouldn't import the `Module` file as you are creating a `TestModule` with Nest's helper functions. This could be leading to you overwriting the `ElasticSearchService` incorrectly and not allowing Nest to inject the proper values.

Answer (score 0):

If you look here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nestjs/elasticsearch it appears that the `ElasticSearchModule` is not *really* a ready to use module, it's more like a factory where you need to call `ElasticsearchModule.register()` or `ElasticsearchModule.registerAsync()` that will return a NestJS module.

```
module = await Test.createTestingModule({
  imports: [ElasticsearchModule.register(...)],
  providers: [ElasticsearchService, clientFactory],
}).compile();
```

Having not used this module before, this is just a best guess, good luck!